# templateData variables return undefined from helper function (docpad.coffee configuration file)

Tags: node.js, scope, coffeescript, docpad

This is my [configuration file](https://gist.github.com/am/38aa2c36f516f90233eb#file-docpad-coffee).

```
docpadConfig = {
    templateData:
        site:
            title: 'hello docpad'

        getTitle: ->
            @site.title

        getString: ->
            'just a string'
}

# Export the DocPad Configuration
module.exports = docpadConfig
```

From a jade layout when I do `title= site.title` it renders ok. When I try to call the helper function `title= getTitle()` the console outputs this:

```
error: An error occured:
ReferenceError: /Volumes/Data/project/am/lab/docpad/hello_docpad/src/layouts/default.html.jade:21
    19|
    20|     //- Our site title and description
  > 21|     title= getTitle()
    22|
    23|     //- Output DocPad produced meta elements
    24|     != getBlock('meta').toHTML()

site is not defined
    at docpadConfig.templateData.getWat (/Volumes/Data/project/am/lab/docpad/hello_docpad/docpad.coffee:10:16)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (/Volumes/Data/project/am/lab/docpad/hello_docpad/node_modules/docpad-plugin-jade/node_modules/jade/lib/jade.js:170:8), <anonymous>:47:64)
```

Looks like I can't access the site object from inside the helper function.

I'm sure I'm missing something trivial, maybe a plugin is needed for this... can't find out "wat" is wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution looking into a similar issue in a [docpad skeleton](https://github.com/docpad/twitter-bootstrap-jade.docpad). This relates to a [bug](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-jade/commit/6a244ef34cce70d5fa971adf6bcebe4a8be8e86d) in the Jade pre-processor.

**Update to `"docpad-plugin-jade": "~2.4.1"` fixes the issue.**